# How can I update heroku requirements.txt?

Tags: python, django, heroku

I've had `pkg-resources==0.0.0` in my requirements.txt so heroku can't run   the app. After removing this string and commiting it still can't.

Tried to remove whole project and create new -- nothing. If I commit again I see "nothing to commit, working tree clean"

```
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Installing python-3.6.8
remote: -----> Installing pip
remote: -----> Installing SQLite3
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote:        Collecting Django==2.2.3 (from -r /tmp/build_00cd1392df5f26408e135a402fc2038d/requirements.txt (line 1))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/39/b0/2138c31bf13e17afc32277239da53e9dfcce27bac8cb68cf1c0123f1fdf5/Django-2.2.3-py3-none-any.whl (7.5MB)
remote:        Collecting pkg-resources==0.0.0 (from -r /tmp/build_00cd1392df5f26408e135a402fc2038d/requirements.txt (line 2))
remote:          Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pkg-resources==0.0.0 (from -r /tmp/build_00cd1392df5f26408e135a402fc2038d/requirements.txt (line 2)) (from versions: )
remote:        No matching distribution found for pkg-resources==0.0.0 (from -r /tmp/build_00cd1392df5f26408e135a402fc2038d/requirements.txt (line 2))
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
```

Comment: Edit your `requirements.txt` and remove `pkg-resources==0.0.0` from it. It's bug. After editing locally push your code to heroku.

Comment: @MD.KhairulBasar, I already said that I did it

Comment: But it's still in your `requirements.txt`. `Collecting pkg-resources==0.0.0`

Comment: Probably you didn't push your commits.

Comment: @MD.KhairulBasar pushed it to heroku master. The log in the question is output from git push heroku master